# MacOS: iterm2, zsh cancelling process with control + c not working, but it works with control + m or control + shift + c

Tags: macos, zsh, macos-mojave, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Ok, this is weird.
My terminal (iterm2 with zsh) exits a command with `control + m` or `control + shift + c` now instead of only `control + c`.

Any ideas on why this is happening?
Thanks!

Comment: Found `stty sane` fixed this problem for me. https://superuser.com/a/253404/184518

Comment: @nrion Did you try that? Did it help?

Answer (score 1):

Try `reset`. I have it in

```
/Users/evar/anaconda/bin//reset
/usr/bin/reset
```

and I think the second one was installed by  macOS itself.